# How do we measure the energies of molecular orbitals?

Tags: quantum-chemistry, molecular-orbital-theory

This question came on my mind after a sentence of a teacher who said during a lesson:

> If you imagine hydrofluoric acid, to make the MO's diagram because the
>   energy gap between the $\text{2s}$ of fluorine and the $\text{1s}$ of
>   hydrogen is quite important you can make the hypothesis at first there
>   is no interaction between both. But experiments show that the bonding
>   MO's of $\ce{HF}$ has an energy a bit different than the energy of the
>   $\text{2s}$ of fluorine.

At first it not supprised me that much, I knew it. But know there is one question.

---

**Question's':**

How is that possible to measure the energy of a specific MO? Is that also possible if there is no electron in the MO or if it is an anti-bonding MO?

Comment: We don't measure them directly (they cannot be as they are not physical ). The quote is most probably about interpreting xps/ups spectrum.

Comment: @Greg We were only speaking about complex shapes. It was just in the introduction.

Comment: Would you elaborate? What complex shapes are you talking about?

Comment: As I said it was in an introduction just to keep some things one mind there are new student at school which never learn about that before that's why teachers need sometime to do things like that. If you read my question, it is not about complex shapes, isn't it? so the answer musn't be about that.